# Get PID from ShellExecute

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, java-native-interface, jna

I am launching a process from ShellExecuteEx, and I really need to get the ProcessID (It's part of the requirement of this class).

Somehow all the important `SHELLEXECUTEINFO` returns null.
So for example if I use this code:

```
exInfo.lpVerb = "open";
exInfo.lpFile = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";
exInfo.nShow  = 5;

ShellExecuteExA(exInfo);
```

It launched CMD.exe. But now I need to get it's PID.
    `exInfo.hwnd` is returning `0`, and `exInfo.hProcess` is returning `null`.
Is this normal behaviour?

I don't really want to resort to using CreateProcess(), because my function should also be able to launch documents like "C:\doc1.docx". This is just a method, in which I cannot predict what is going to be launched (So I cannot know the window title/classname from beforehand, get the hWnd from there and then get the PID).

Could somebody kindly point out my mistake? Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain further on how to get the PID from ShellExecuteInfo because I am looking for a way myself.

Comment: `DWORD PID = GetProcessId(exInfo.hProcess);` this is the one that I am currently using. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a flag (SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS) in exInfo.fMask

Comment: Be aware that `ShellExecuteEx` can returns success without creating a process. (For example, if the handler is a single-instance app.)