# ShellExecuteEx function always returning error code 5 (C++)

Tags: shellexecute, shellexecuteex

I need to start a process and have access to the PID, so I am trying to use ShellExecuteEx.  I am attempting to open a batch file.  However, no matter how I pass the parameters and no matter where the file is located and what permission's I have on the file, the function is returning with Error Code 5: Access is denied.

- The File is located in the same location as the config files that have already been read successfully.
- The File is set for full access permissions with any user.
- It does this with any file type.  I've tried just opening text files with the same outcome (Error 5)
- If I use ShellExecute() instead, the batch file is run successfully.

Here is some of the code I've tried:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO exInfo;
exInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
exInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
exInfo.lpVerb = "open";
exInfo.lpFile = "C:\\batchtest.bat";
exInfo.nShow = SW_NORMAL;
BOOL hReturnCode = ShellExecute(&exInfo);
DWORD LastError = GetLastError();
```

I've also tried:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO exInfo;
exInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
exInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
exInfo.lpVerb = "open";
exInfo.lpFile = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";
exInfo.lpParameters = "batchtest.bat";
```

And many variations of the above.

Also, I've tried something really simple like from here:
[Get PID from ShellExecute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620322/get-pid-from-shellexecute)

to no avail.

However this:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "C:\\testbat.bat", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

works without an error.  Unfortunately, I need the PID, so I can't use ShellExecute.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I feel like I've exhausted all of my options.

Environment:
VS 2008
Windows 7

**EDIT**: fixed the code to "C:\batchtest.bat"; as suggested. (Still same result)

Comment: this maybe answered already.. here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620322/get-pid-from-shellexecute

Comment: Hi mig, I referenced that answer in my question.  It did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.
In order to run batch file and I guess some other types of exe's on Windows 7, you have to elevate the call using the lpVerb = _TEXT("runas") -- even if you have UAC turned off.  This isn't documented in the SHELLEXECUTEINFO structure documentation on MDSN (it isn't even given as an option), since it says: "The following verbs are commonly used"
The final code was as follows:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO exInfo;
exInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
exInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS; //allows the PID to be returned
exInfo.hwnd = NULL;
exInfo.lpVerb =  _TEXT("runas"); //elevates for Windows 7
exInfo.lpFile = "C:\\BatchTest.bat";
exInfo.lpParameters = NULL;
exInfo.nShow = SW_MAXIMIZE;
exInfo.hInstApp = NULL;
exInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
BOOL hReturnCode = ShellExecuteEx(&exInfo);
```

I hope that helps others out.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the line

```
exInfo.lpFile = "C:\\batchtest.exe";
```

be

```
exInfo.lpFile = "C:\\batchtest.bat";
```

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes, it should.  I tried both and must have copied the wrong code.  Both yield the same result-- Error code 5