# ShellExecute - ERROR code 5

Tags: c++, notepad++, tdm-gcc

I am using Notepad++ with TDM-GCC. My computer is 2Gb RAM Windows 10 32 bit 3.30 GHz. When I execute my simple program, it shows error.

```
Access is denied.
An attempt was made to execute the below command.
Command: D:\Deane\Github\CPP_Projects\AnalysisName\main.bat
Arguments:
Error Code: 5
```

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdEKQ.png)

I follow this: [ShellExecuteEx function always returning error code 5 (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761582/shellexecuteex-function-always-returning-error-code-5-c)

Program's code (if necessary):

```
/* AnalysisName Program - written by Vo Tran Nha Linh */

#include <iostream> // Input and Output library.
using namespace std;

int main()
    {
    string name;
    cout << "Hello friend! It's nice to meet you, what is your name?" << endl;  // Ask the name.
    cin >> name; // Input name.
    cout << "Hello " << name << ". Your name is interesting." << endl; // Have a greeting.
    cout << "Your name has " << name.length() << "letters." << endl; // Show the name's length.
    cout << "It starts with " << name.front() << "letter." << endl; // Show the first letter of the name.
    cout << "It ends with " << name.back() << "letter." << endl; // Show the last letter of the name.

    return 0;

}
```

But it doesn't active, please give me a help. Thank you very much!

Comment: And how is `main.bat` related to the given C++ program? Is it compilation script?

Comment: @VTT I just follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761582/shellexecuteex-function-always-returning-error-code-5-c

Comment: Code 5 - Access denied means you don't have the permissions to run the programs with standard user rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem solved!

I miss Visual C++ Redistributable 2008 and 2010.

Moderators please close my topic. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++` Right mouse click the Notpad++.exe file click properties & under the compatability Tab UN-TICK run the program as administrator box DONE.
Refer to [this link](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/10945/shellexecute-failed-2-is-this-command-correct-fix).

Comment: Thank you but my error code is 5 and it's 2. However, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

this solved it for me:
right click on the file that won't run (in my case a .cmd file)
check the 'Unblock' checkbox next to the remark "This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer"